# Problems superclassing stream.Duplex

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I am trying to implement a readable stream by extending stream.Readable.

According to the docs all I have to do is implement _read().

What I do not understand is what to do when in _read I have no data or how to trigger another call to _read once I do have data again. I do not see a concept in Readable to cope with data being delivered slowly or delayed. I can see that _read() is being called right after the pipe() function was called.

If at any point in _read I have no data I have to return without delivering and it seems that _read is never called again. I tried to emit a readable event once data is ready but that doesn't trigger a call to _read.

This problem does not only occur on start, but might happen whenever my source takes its time to deliver. Does stream.Readable not support slow sources ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_read()` is just a signal that lets you know more data can/should be read from your upstream source. This matters most when you `push()` data to the stream and `push()` return `false`. When that happens, you should not push any more data until `_read()` is called again.

There's nothing actually stopping you from pushing any amount of data at any time, but then you may end up buffering way too much data in memory if you don't check `push()`'s return value and act on it accordingly.

Additionally when inheriting/subclasses `Readable`, you will want to make sure you call the superclass constructor (for ES6 classes) or the `Readable` constructor within the context of your stream instance (`this`) in your own constructor (for pre-ES6 classes/prototypal inheritance) (e.g. `Readable.call(this, { /*Optional Readable settings*/ })`.

Comment: If you believe it's not clear enough, consider submitting a PR to the node repo with a change in wording. Sometimes it can be difficult for those of us who've been around the code base for a long time to describe it well enough for users coming to the project for the first time.